# Inserting an item to database for multiple times

Tags: sql, asp.net

In my program in asp.net with back end sql, I need to add same data multiple times.
Eg: I need to insert an item with Num-1212,Qty-3,Date-20-02-15,code-A11 in database table table1.

At the same time I need to add this data into another table table2 as given below. The number of time item repeat is equal to the qty. Pls help.

[image]

```
String str1 = "insert into table2 select * from table1;";
SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da1.SelectCommand = xp1;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1, "Code");
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
con.Close();
```

I tried this but it will insert it on 1 time

Comment: And what is your problem ? What have you tried that did not work ?

Comment: You can always run your code several times as per your quantity, if it runs correctly right now.

Comment: try Google search sometime

Comment: i suggest to use Bulk Copy for that in case u have big Qty

Comment: String str1 = "insert into table2 select * from table1;";
        SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da1.SelectCommand = xp1;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1, "Code");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
        con.Close();
I tried this but it will insert it on 1 time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Proc [untested]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AStoredProcWrittenmForMe] ( @num int,
                                            @qty int, 
                                            @code nvarchar(10), 
                                            @date DateTime)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @newId int;
  INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT @num, @qty, @code, @date;
  SET @newId = @@IDENTITY;


  DECLARE @loop int = @qty;
  WHILE @loop > 0 
    INSERT INTO Table12
      SELECT @newId, @num, @qty, @code, @date;
    SET @loop = ~loop - 1;
  BEGIN

  END

END
GO
```

You can call it via an SQL Command ExecuteReader....
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Perhaps you might TRY to do that yourself....

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure to do this and call that.

Then you only have 1 call from your application to the database rather than multiple hits.

Comment: A trigger would be even better, when insert into table1.